# How should I omit?

Tags: grammar

> *The author raised the question of whether architecture can determine political relations. First explains from the perspective of etymology
> that for antagonistic space, the word “Agon” has the original meaning
> of “struggle”,”fight” and “contest”.*

Hi ,
this is a sentence I wrote for my essay. Is it correct to omit the subject in a sentence by this way? I want to say "the author" first explains the word.....

Comment: What you are saying here is that the author's surname is First.

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

- "Initially, he explained... OR Initially, she explained... (depending on author gender)"

Similarly to the above you can have:

- "At first, he/she explained...."

Alternatively (but a bit too long in my opinion):

- "The author raised the question of whether architecture can determine political relations where he/she explained/explains from the perspective..."

Moreover you can say: "The author, Mr. Edward Jenkings, raised the question...." and in the next sentence have "Mr. Jenknings explains from the perspective..."

Hope you found this useful,

Regards